# Problems with re-arranging an infinite sum formally

Tags: calculus, power-series

I have a Problem with the formal steps of rearranging a sum of sums. I want to write $$t^2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_n t^n+ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n t^n$$ given $a_0=0$ as $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(na_n+a_{n+1})t^{n+1}$$

If i write the first sum as $t^2(a_1+2a_2t+3a_3t^2+\dots)+a_0+(a_1t+a_2t^2+a_3t^3+...)$, i have no problem with re-arranging it to $a_1t+(a_1+a_2)t^2+(2a_2+a_3)t^3+\dots$, which equals the second sum.

But what are the "formal steps" by manipulating the sum without writing it out suggestively?